# Let $G$ be a group and $K$ be subgroup of order $p^a$. I am trying to show that $|\{H \leq G : K \subset H, |H|=p^{a+b}\}| \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $K$ be subgroup of order $p^a$.  I am trying to show that $$|\{H \leq G :  K \subset H, |H|=p^{a+b}\}| \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$ for each b fixed & for all $a+b$ such that $p^{a+b}$ divides $|G|$.

In Sylow's Theorem, we have the option to consider conjugation by one Sylow $p$-subgroup on the set of $p$-Sylow subgroups. But here what can be done?

Comment: Try to think by induction on b

Comment: Do you want the $H$'s to be Sylow subgroups?

Comment: No only p subgroups

Comment: First reduce (by induction) to the case where $b = 1$. Then in that case, the number of subgroups of order $p^{a+1}$ that contain $K$ are in bijection with the subgroups of order $p$ in $N_G(K)/K$.

Comment: Yeah Mikko Korhonen, p.t the order is congruent to one mod p...